# JSOUP Redirect Script

Tags: java, android, html, post, jsoup

I am making this app and it basically involves the user to login to [this site](http://erp.mitpune.com/)

So my current code is

```
Connection conn = Jsoup.connect("http://erp.mitpune.com/")
    .cookies(cookies)
    .header( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
    .header("Referer","http://erp.mitpune.com/AdminLogin.aspx")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.89 Safari/537.36")
    .data("txtPassword", "******")
    .data("__LASTFOCUS", "")
    .data("__EVENTTARGET", "btnLogin")
    .data("__EVENTARGUMENT", "")
    .data("__VIEWSTATE", "/wEPDwUINDA4MDU2ODdkZGYVkCI+Zarbu9B42es/RUu7ZNbD")
    .data("__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "B8B84CAE")
    .data("hdnMsg", "")
    .data("txtUserId", "*******")
    .data("__ASYNCPOST", "true")
    .timeout(0)
    .followRedirects(true)
    .data("ScriptManager1", "UpdatePanel1|btnLogin")
    .method(Connection.Method.POST);

Connection.Response resl = conn.execute();
```

Which gives me the output as

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  69|dataItem||
  <script type="text/javascript">window.location="about:blank"</script>|62|pageRedirect||/Main.aspx?Usertype=STUDENT&amp;modulecode=WEBSTUDACS&amp;Userselect=S|
 </body>
</html>
```

Which I would say is correct.

The code I use to connect to the redirected page is

```
Connection conn1 = Jsoup.connect("http://erp.mitpune.com/Main.aspx")
    .data("Usertype","STUDENT")
    .data("modulecode","WEBSTUDACS")
    .data("Userselect","S")
    .cookies(cookies)
    .method(Connection.Method.GET);

Connection.Response res2 = conn1.execute();

Document doc = res2.parse();
```

Now the problem I am facing is how do I continue this connection? Cause when I try connecting to the redirected page ,with the cookie, it just sends me back to the login page or shows me the code of the redirected page as if the user isn't logged in. Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: please show the code that you use to connect to the redirected page

Comment: @NicolasFilotto Thanks :) ,edited it